# Split a matrix into submatrices by rownames

Tags: r, matrix, split

Basically I'm wondering if there is any way to make the `split` function return matrices with same dimnames when used onto a matrix. Here is a MWE:

```
m <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3, dimnames = list(c('a', 'a', 'b'), LETTERS[1:3]))
ms <- split(a, f = rownames(a))
ms$a
[1] 1 2 4 5 7 8
```

while I want `ms$a` to be a matrix like:

```
matrix(ms$a, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c('a'), LETTERS[1:3]))
  A B C
a 1 4 7
a 2 5 8
```

Comment: If you don't mind a list of data.frames as result, you can use `split(as.data.frame(m), rownames(m))`

Comment: `as.data.frame(m)` returns an error `duplicate row.names`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the sequence of rows by the row names and then subset the rows of the matrix using the index.

```
lapply(split(1:nrow(m), rownames(m)), function(i) m[i,])
```